# keyboard mousepad not working after 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, kernel, keyboard

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 on my HP zbook Studio, I have a few issues. The first I'd like to get, is that the mousepad and keyboard are not working (from the logging prompt).

Oddly, it works in the the grub menu and I can navigate to choose different options. It turns out that the keyboard/pad work in kernel 4.4, but not in 4.15 or 5.

I don't know if it is relevant, but in 4.4, the nvidia driver is loaded but not working, whereas it is fine in the other kernels.

I've tried a few suggestions from the forums, but nothing worked, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for the version of your efficient kernel from [kernel.ubuntu.com](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and then try to install all the packages using

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Hope this will solve your problem.